# Prevent "hostmaster" subdomain from redirecting to the main site

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, soa-record

I host `mainsite.com` and `othersite.net` on a single Debian 8 server with nginx/1.6.2. Recently I discovered that Google indexed `hostmaster.othersite.net` and this subdomain shows full content of `mainsite.com`.

I see this subdomain as a `SOA` record pointing to `hostmaster@othersite.net` in DNS lookup tools but it's not in the hoster's control panel. Where can it be located and how can I remove this redirection?

DNS records:

```
CNAME | *.mainsite.com  | is an alias of mainsite.com.     | 1800
A     | mainsite.com    | directs to xx.xx.xx.xx           | 1800 
NS    | mainsite.com    | directs to ns1.digitalocean.com. | 1800 
NS    | mainsite.com    | directs to ns2.digitalocean.com. | 1800 
NS    | mainsite.com    | directs to ns3.digitalocean.com. | 1800 


CNAME | *.othersite.net | is an alias of othersite.net.    | 1800
A     | othersite.net   | directs to xx.xx.xx.xx           | 1800
NS    | othersite.net   | directs to ns3.digitalocean.com. | 1800
NS    | othersite.net   | directs to ns1.digitalocean.com. | 1800
NS    | othersite.net   | directs to ns2.digitalocean.com. | 1800
```

Simplified `nginx.conf` (only `location` and www redirects removed):

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl default_server;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mainsite.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mainsite.com/privkey.pem;

        server_name mainsite.com;
        root /home/mainsite/html;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mainsite.com;
        return 301 https://mainsite.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/othersite.net/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/othersite.net/privkey.pem;

        server_name othersite.net;
        root /home/othersite/html;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name othersite.net;
        return 301 https://othersite.net$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: SOA is not a redirection, it's a required field in DNS.  It denotes an email address (using a . instead of an at), so hostmaster.othersite.net just means the DNS SOA has hostmaster@othersite.net as the contact for the zone.  If you want 'hostmaster.othersite.net' to not resolve, you need to remove your wildcard.  That's the point of a wildcard, resolve every name in the zone that isn't explicitly configured.

Comment: `default_server` is presumably making that `server` block the default for any hostname you don't explicitly list in a `server_name` field. Since you don't specify another server for `hostmaster.othersite.net`, it uses that one by default.